# prawn requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0 but I already have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, prawn

I want to install prawn for my Ruby on Rails. Here are information.

I'm using linux mint.

command 1: rvm list

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

command 2:  ruby --version

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

command 3: sudo gem install prawn

```
ERROR:  Error installing prawn:
    prawn requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

Why does prawn sees me using ruby version less than 2.0.0? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this might be because you're using `sudo` to install prawn which RVM advises against. As a result the prawn gem gets installed as root outside of RVM's control.
Try again without sudo?

Comment: Thanks you, the gem is now installed.